# How do I move whole individual faces that are connected in the center by mirror modifier?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I am sorry, that I didn't post an image, but I guess everybody knows the problem.

When the mesh is mirrorred moving any face on one side moves it on the other. But faces that are connected in the middle by mirror axis always move together. I understand it is because there is only one non-symetrical group of vertices in the middle.

Is there any shortcut that allows to disconnect those faces while mowing them ? I remember there is B shortcut for when Insetting separate faces in the middle, there must be something like this for simple moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck *Clipping* under the *Mirror* modifier

[image: Mirror modifier]

Comment: Yes Yes thank You for so fast answer :)